# Why is replaying this log file is causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: kdb

```
DB+ 3.6 2018.07.30 Copyright (C) 1993-2018 Kx Systems
l64/ 16()core
```

I am trying to replay a log file of 1.7G.

I get the following error :

```
m1 -6341068259609826952
wsfull
Sorry, this application or an associated library has encountered a fatal error and will exit.
If known, please email the steps to reproduce this error to tech@kx.com
with a copy of the kdb+ startup banner and the info printed below.
Thank you.
SIGSEGV: Fault address 0x3752e00000c93
```

the upd function is a simple : upd:upsert

```
q).Q.w[]
used| 667888
heap| 67108864
peak| 67108864
wmax| 0
mmap| 0
mphy| 270882623488
syms| 3459
symw| 228104
```

none of the -11!(-1 -2) work. replay works fine for first ~2000 records

Answer (score 2):

There were some checks added on 2019.11.04 around this

```
added further integrity checks to streaming execute (-11!x) to avoid wsfull or segfault on corrupted/incomplete log files. e.g.
`:log set();h:hopen`:log;h enlist(`upd;1#0xff);hclose h;`:log1 1: (-5_(read1`:log)),0xffffffff0000ffffff;-11!`:log1 / wsfull or segfaulted
```

I would try again with a more recent version of kdb+, albeit you'll still have some issue with the replay

Jason